# How to present scalable time data as a factor in the r ggplot package? (i.e. 1 hour, 5 hour, 10 hour)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have groups of data at 0 hour, 3 hour, 12 hour, 24 hour, 48hour,... I want to graph that data so that the scale of the time is preserved.

```
runs <- c(1:25)
hours <- as.factor(c(0, 3, 12, 24, 48, 96))
treatments <- (c("a","b","c","d"))
things <- as.numeric(runif(600, min=1, max=15))
type <- expand.grid(hours,treatments,runs)
data.df <- data.frame(type,things)

names(data.df)[names(data.df)=="Var1"] <- "hour"
names(data.df)[names(data.df)=="Var2"] <- "treatments"

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.df, aes(x=as.factor(hour), y=things, fill=treatments)) +
   geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

I need the data in the graph to be scaled, so the 3 hour tick is approx 1/4 of the distance to the 12 hour tick, and the 12 hour is half the distance to the 24 hour.

Using Stefan's answer we arrived at this plot:
[image]

Using this code change

```
ggplot(data.df, aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(hours)), y=things, fill=things, group = hours))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(as.character(hours)))
```

But unfortunately, I cannot change the group/fill to show the treatment.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for providing a reproducible example for us. However, it is very difficult to copy your code as it is because of `>` and `+` in the code. We have to manually remove it from each line that we copy.

Comment: I will remove that! Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you could convert your `hours` variable to a numeric and map `hours` on the `group` aesthetic:

```r
hours <- as.factor(c(0, 3, 12, 24, 48, 96))
things <- runif(36, min=1, max=10)
data.df <- data.frame(hours,things)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.df, aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(hours)), y=things, fill=things, group = hours))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(as.character(hours)))
```

[image]

**EDIT** For you updated question you could get the desired result by mapping both `hour` and `treatment` on the `group` aes using e.g `interaction`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.df, aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(hour)), y=things, fill=treatments, group = interaction(hour, treatments)))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(as.character(hours)))
```

[image]

Comment: I had to modify the question after your answer. This did work! But I realize I did not provide all the necessary information. I have a treatment group in my data that I would like to show in the plot. I updated the question to include this. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I just made an edit. Maybe this fits your needs. Best S.

Comment: Thank you! Now I just have to figure out how to make it prettier.

Comment: Yep. These small box plots are no beauties. (;